# copying iterator into container (containing pointers to typedef)?

Tags: c++, iterator, typedef

I have a user-defined class `Node`, a typedef `VERTEX` and am trying to fill up a vector of `VERTEX*`, by aiming the pointers at elements in a hash_map containing `VERTEX`. The problem is that when I try to aim the pointer at the iterator, an error comes up telling me 'iterator types are incompatible'. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
class Node
{
public:
Node(){DEGREE = 0;}
bool HAS_OUTLINK;//using size() instead
vector <int> IN;
vector <int> OUT;
//string URL;//not strictly necessary
double PAGE_RANK;
double I_A;
int DEGREE;//referring to outdegree
};
    typedef pair <int, Node> VERTEX;
    void top_ten (hash_map<int, Node>& G){
       vector <VERTEX*> top10;// then after some initilisation...
       hash_map <int, Node>::iterator i;
       for (i = G.begin(); i != G.end(); i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
             double &temp = i->second.PAGE_RANK;
             VERTEX *compare = top10[j];
             if (compare->second.PAGE_RANK < temp){
                compare->first = i->first;
                compare->second = i->second;//where the mistake is
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

I have also tried simply using `compare = i` and `compare = &i` although neither of those are accepted by the compiler.

Comment: The IDE tells me that no operator matches those operands

Comment: Does your Node class have an assignment operator that is public?

Comment: You really need to show the definition of `Node`. Based on where you're pointing out an error, it appears that it's probably not copyable. Make it copyable, then just use `*compare = *i;`. Poor algorithm though. I'd use a priority queue, insert each new item, then remove the smallest if the size is greater than 10.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I tried `*compare = *i;` but it is still telling me that the iterator types are incompatible for some reason.

Comment: you need to show the code.

Comment: @user1922001: As I said, "*Make it copyable*, then..."

Comment: @AnonMail: I just removed the `compare->first = i->first;` and `compare->first = i->second;` but inserted `*compare = *i; ` to where they were

Comment: @JerryCoffin: How do I go about making it copyable?

Comment: @user1922001: without seeing the code, I can't even guess.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: but what does the error of incompatible iterator types refer to? Are compare and i not of the same type?

Comment: @user1922001: `compare` and `i` are not the same type, but `*compare` and `*i` should be.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: can you please tell me what types they are, since they are not the same type?

Comment: @user1922001: At least as you've shown them above, one is a pointer, the other an iterator to a hash table (which probably *can't* be a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

do you need to deference `i`. i dont think you do, its not a pointer

change

```
compare->first = i->first;
```

to

```
compare->first = i.first;
```

and so on

Comment: It tells me that the argument list for template "stdext::hash_map" is missing if I try to remove <int, Node>

Comment: i iterates through the hash_map G, which contains my typedef VERTEX, which is actually typedef pair <int, Node> VERTEX, so I do need to use -> instead of .